# Error when compiling nim file to generate javascript Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-generation, nim-lang

I have tried to compile nim file to generate javascript code but I got this error: `Error: OS module not ported to your operating system!`

using this command: `nim js -d:nodejs -r myFile.nim`. The problem is related to : `import os` in this file. Is there any solution?

Comment: The problem is that the OS module is available only when compiling to C/C++. What are the particular functions, which you want to use?

Comment: I want to compile to js this script : https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/tests/benchmarks/quicksort.nim

Comment: You can remove the `import os` line. It doesn't seem to be used in the rest of the code.